# Issue with hover property on <li> element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to apply hover property on `li` element of sidebar, its working but icon tag is not showing hover effect. I want icon to show hover effect along with `li`'s hover effect.
Below is the code:

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;    
}

.wrapper .sidebar{

    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #00B6E1;
    /* padding: 30px 0; */
    height: 100%;
 
}
.wrapper .sidebar ul li{


    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #064E88;
    /* border-top: 1px solid; */
    /* color: white; */
    font-weight: 400;
}


.wrapper .sidebar ul li a{

    padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover{

    background-color: #064E88;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul class="side">
                <li><a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-columns-gap fa-lg icon-red"></i> </a>Dashboard</li>
                <li><a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-graph-up-arrow"></i> </a>Reporting</li>
                <li><a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-send-check"></i> </a>Sending</li>
                <li><a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-envelope"></i> </a>Recieving</li>
                <li><a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-person-check"></i> </a>Verification</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply give an extra class to each `<i>` tag and refer it to CSS with `li:hover` selector. (I've given *icon*)

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul class="side">
                
            <li><a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-columns-gap fa-lg icon-red icon"></i></a>Dashboard</li> <!-- Extra class 'icon'-->
            <li><a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-graph-up-arrow icon"></i> </a>Reporting</li>
            <li><a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-send-check icon"></i> </a>Sending</li>
            <li><a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-envelope icon"></i> </a>Recieving</li>
            <li><a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-person-check icon"></i> </a>Verification</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
/*Referring the class 'icon' with 'li:hover'*/
.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover, li:hover .icon{
    background-color: #064E88;
    color: white;
}
```

`li:hover .icon` as whole represents the element with class 'icon' inside the hovered 'li' tag.
We need to separate it with '`li:hover`' so that the effect shows on both the hovered li and `<i>` tag.

To change the properties of an element when clicked (or the selected tab), we will give the selected tab the 'active' class, which will be removed and given to another element when the other element is clicked.

```js
let tabContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("side")[0]; //This container contains all the tab items.
let tabPane = tabContainer.getElementsByTagName("li"); //Returns a list of all elements inside the container with tag name 'li', that it, it contains all the tab items.

for (let i = 0; i < tabPane.length; i++) {
  //Add an event listener to every tab item that will trigger the given function on on click.
  //Note: Inside the function, tabsPane[i] is the tab item clicked.
  tabPane[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    tabContainer.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove("active"); //Remove the 'active' class from the currently selected tab.
    tabPane[i].classList.add("active"); //Give the 'active' class to the tab item clicked.
  });
};
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;    
}
.wrapper .sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #00B6E1;
  /* padding: 30px 0; */
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper .sidebar ul li{
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #064E88;
  /* border-top: 1px solid; */
  /* color: white; */
  font-weight: 400;
}
.wrapper .sidebar ul li a {padding: 10px;}

/*Referring the class 'icon' with 'li:hover'*/
.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover, li:hover .icon{
  background-color: #064E88;
  color: white;
}
/*Separate properties of the active or selected tab*/
.active {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul class="side">
            <!--Default active tab-->
            <li class="active"><a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-columns-gap fa-lg icon-red icon"></i></a>Dashboard</li> <!-- Extra class 'icon'-->
            <li><a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-graph-up-arrow icon"></i> </a>Reporting</li>
            <li><a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-send-check icon"></i> </a>Sending</li>
            <li><a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-envelope icon"></i> </a>Recieving</li>
            <li><a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-person-check icon"></i> </a>Verification</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I applied suggested changes, only icon part is now showing hover effect not <li>

Comment: .wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover .icon{

    background-color:#9cdceb;
    
    font-weight: 600;
}

Comment: Did you mentioned both '.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover' and 'li:hover .icon' separetely such that they are separated by a comma?
Cause if you haven't, then the CSS will apply the properties to the .'icon' in the hovered 'li' element.

Comment: Ansh i did .wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover, li:hover .icon{

    background-color:#9cdceb;
    
    font-weight: 600;
}

Comment: I've tested the code and it works. I dunno why it ain't working for ya... :(

Comment: Thanks Ansh its working now, i believe edit was not saved when tried last time. Thanks Alot bro :)

Comment: Ansh one more problem came into my way, actually i am learning html css by practicing things, What i want is to make side menu item and when hover menu items background color and color of <li> must change, this was achieved with your help. But now i also want when I click on any menu item background color must change(will become active) till I click on another menu item.

Comment: I guess you will need to use JavaScript for that.

Comment: I've uploaded the final solution in the edit.